# countifs does not make difference in the value has 0 in start

Tags: excel

Why Countifs is not considering value with 0 at start its answer should be 1 and 1 because B1 and B2 are two different value.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think COUNTIFS silently converts "text-that-looks-like-numbers" to numbers. Helpful "feature". You should use an alternate formula if you need an exact match.

Comment: Which can be the best formula to get exact match with having such values in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1=$A$1:$A$2)*(B1=$B$1:$B$2))
```

[image]

Comment: That's great how I missed this. Thank you very much.